# É normal a passagem de variáveis nulas do lado do cliente para o lado do servico?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Meu objetivo é criar três aplicações: em WCF, em ASP.NEW Web API e outra em WPF.

**A minha dúvida é a seguinte:**

É normal, os dados que inicializamos no lado do cliente ou seja (WPF) e que passamos para o servico (WCF) venha a null?

Exemplo do meu código - **WPF**

```
       InitializeComponent();
       _gestaoInformacao = new Gestao_InformacaoUsersClient();

       newUser = new Utilizador { Username = "Joao" };
       _gestaoInformacao.addNovoUtilizador(newUser);
```

**WCF:**

```
 public void addNovoUtilizador(Utilizador newUser)
    {

        projectContext.Users.Add(newUser);
        projectContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Classe Utilizador:

```
public class Utilizador
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    private int id_utilizador;

    [DataMember]
    private String _username;

    [DataMember]
    public String Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    private String _password;

    [DataMember]
    public String Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }






}
```

A questão aqui, é que quando passo o *newUser* do WPF para o WCF e corro o debug para ver a informação que passa,  o VS diz que todos os dados do utilizador estão a *null* (pelo menos o username devia ter dados)

[image: Demontração dos Dados nulos]

Estes dados, é normal estarem nulos, ou algo está errado? Talvez com as configurações dos Services.

Comment: Isso parece um problema de serialização. Não ficou claro no seu exemplo, mas como você marcou os atributos da classe *Utilizador* com `DataMember`, você também marcou a classe com `DataContract`?

Comment: Sim, é normal a passagem de variáveis nulas do lado do cliente para o lado do serviço.